# Minimap for D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to figure out the mechanism for minimap in D3JS. I find a sample project that you can find [here](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2013/11/26/d3-minimap-pan-and-zoom-demo/#comment-2935). I copied all the codes given in [codepen](http://codepen.io/billdwhite/pen/lCAdi) and run a simple HTTP server of python as "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000". When I open the link as "localhost:3000" I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null d3.v3.min.js:3
ya.attr d3.v3.min.js:3
minimap.target minimap.js:411
canvas minimap.js:173
ya.call d3.v3.min.js:3
(anonymous function)
```

Since I copied and pasted this code, I couldn't figure out the error. Do you have any idea about the reason?

The codes given in codepen is copied as follows:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="minimap.css" >
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="minimap.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h5 class="title">Use mousewheel to zoom. Drag image or minimap rectangle to pan.</h5>
<div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

minimap.css

```
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.title {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.canvas .wrapper.outer > .background {
    fill: #000000;
}
.canvas .wrapper.inner > .background {
    fill: #CCCCCC;
    cursor: move;
}
.canvas .background {
    fill: #F6F6F6;
    stroke: #333333;
    cursor: move;
}
.canvas .panCanvas {
    cursor: move;
}

.canvas .minimap .frame .background {
    stroke: #111111;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    fill: #000000;
    fill: url(#minimapGradient);
    filter: url(#minimapDropShadow);
    cursor: move;
}
```

minimap.js

```
d3.demo = {};

/** CANVAS **/
d3.demo.canvas = function() {

  "use strict";

  var width           = 500,
    height          = 500,
    zoomEnabled     = true,
    dragEnabled     = true,
    scale           = 1,
    translation     = [0,0],
    base            = null,
    wrapperBorder   = 2,
    minimap         = null,
    minimapPadding  = 20,
    minimapScale    = 0.25;

  function canvas(selection) {

    base = selection;

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-width / 2, width / 2])
      .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-height / 2, height / 2])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var zoomHandler = function(newScale) {
      if (!zoomEnabled) { return; }
      if (d3.event) {
        scale = d3.event.scale;
      } else {
        scale = newScale;
      }
      if (dragEnabled) {
        var tbound = -height * scale,
          bbound = height  * scale,
          lbound = -width  * scale,
          rbound = width   * scale;
        // limit translation to thresholds
        translation = d3.event ? d3.event.translate : [0, 0];
        translation = [
          Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
          Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
        ];
      }

      d3.select(".panCanvas, .panCanvas .bg")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");

      minimap.scale(scale).render();
    }; // startoff zoomed in a bit to show pan/zoom rectangle

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(xScale)
      .y(yScale)
      .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
      .on("zoom.canvas", zoomHandler);

    var svg = selection.append("svg")
      .attr("class", "svg canvas")
      .attr("width",  width  + (wrapperBorder*2) + minimapPadding*2 + (width*minimapScale))
      .attr("height", height + (wrapperBorder*2) + minimapPadding*2)
      .attr("shape-rendering", "auto");

    var svgDefs = svg.append("defs");

    svgDefs.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "wrapperClipPath")
      .attr("class", "wrapper clipPath")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svgDefs.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "minimapClipPath")
      .attr("class", "minimap clipPath")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      //.attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + minimapPadding) + "," + (minimapPadding/2) + ")")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var filter = svgDefs.append("svg:filter")
      .attr("id", "minimapDropShadow")
      .attr("x", "-20%")
      .attr("y", "-20%")
      .attr("width", "150%")
      .attr("height", "150%");

    filter.append("svg:feOffset")
      .attr("result", "offOut")
      .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
      .attr("dx", "1")
      .attr("dy", "1");

    filter.append("svg:feColorMatrix")
      .attr("result", "matrixOut")
      .attr("in", "offOut")
      .attr("type", "matrix")
      .attr("values", "0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0");

    filter.append("svg:feGaussianBlur")
      .attr("result", "blurOut")
      .attr("in", "matrixOut")
      .attr("stdDeviation", "10");

    filter.append("svg:feBlend")
      .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
      .attr("in2", "blurOut")
      .attr("mode", "normal");

    var minimapRadialFill = svgDefs.append("radialGradient")
      .attr({
        id:"minimapGradient",
        gradientUnits:"userSpaceOnUse",
        cx:"500",
        cy:"500",
        r:"400",
        fx:"500",
        fy:"500"
      });
    minimapRadialFill.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "0%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#FFFFFF");
    minimapRadialFill.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "40%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#EEEEEE");
    minimapRadialFill.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "100%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#E0E0E0");

    var outerWrapper = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "wrapper outer")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + minimapPadding + ")");

    outerWrapper.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width + wrapperBorder*2)
      .attr("height", height + wrapperBorder*2);

    var innerWrapper = outerWrapper.append("g")
      .attr("class", "wrapper inner")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#wrapperClipPath)")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (wrapperBorder) + "," + (wrapperBorder) + ")")
      .call(zoom);

    innerWrapper.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var panCanvas = innerWrapper.append("g")
      .attr("class", "panCanvas")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

    panCanvas.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    minimap = d3.demo.minimap()
      .zoom(zoom)
      .target(panCanvas)
      .minimapScale(minimapScale)
      .x(width + minimapPadding)
      .y(minimapPadding);

    svg.call(minimap);

    // startoff zoomed in a bit to show pan/zoom rectangle
    zoom.scale(1.75);
    zoomHandler(1.75);

    /** ADD SHAPE **/
    canvas.addItem = function(item) {
      panCanvas.node().appendChild(item.node());
      minimap.render();
    };

    /** RENDER **/
    canvas.render = function() {
      svgDefs
        .select(".clipPath .background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      svg
        .attr("width",  width  + (wrapperBorder*2) + minimapPadding*2 + (width*minimapScale))
        .attr("height", height + (wrapperBorder*2));

      outerWrapper
        .select(".background")
        .attr("width", width + wrapperBorder*2)
        .attr("height", height + wrapperBorder*2);

      innerWrapper
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (wrapperBorder) + "," + (wrapperBorder) + ")")
        .select(".background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      panCanvas
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .select(".background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      minimap
        .x(width + minimapPadding)
        .y(minimapPadding)
        .render();
    };

    canvas.zoomEnabled = function(isEnabled) {
      if (!arguments.length) { return zoomEnabled }
      zoomEnabled = isEnabled;
    };

    canvas.dragEnabled = function(isEnabled) {
      if (!arguments.length) { return dragEnabled }
      dragEnabled = isEnabled;
    };

    canvas.reset = function() {
      d3.transition().duration(750).tween("zoom", function() {
        var ix = d3.interpolate(xScale.domain(), [-width  / 2, width  / 2]),
          iy = d3.interpolate(yScale.domain(), [-height / 2, height / 2]),
          iz = d3.interpolate(scale, 1);
        return function(t) {
          zoom.scale(iz(t)).x(x.domain(ix(t))).y(y.domain(iy(t)));
          zoomed(iz(t));
        };
      });
    };
  }


  //============================================================
  // Accessors
  //============================================================


  canvas.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = parseInt(value, 10);
    return this;
  };

  canvas.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = parseInt(value, 10);
    return this;
  };

  canvas.scale = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return scale; }
    scale = value;
    return this;
  };

  return canvas;
};


/** MINIMAP **/
d3.demo.minimap = function() {

  "use strict";

  var minimapScale    = 0.15,
    scale           = 1,
    zoom            = null,
    base            = null,
    target          = null,
    width           = 0,
    height          = 0,
    x               = 0,
    y               = 0,
    frameX          = 0,
    frameY          = 0;

  function minimap(selection) {

    base = selection;

    var container = selection.append("g")
      .attr("class", "minimap")
      .call(zoom);

    zoom.on("zoom.minimap", function() {
      scale = d3.event.scale;
    });


    minimap.node = container.node();

    var frame = container.append("g")
      .attr("class", "frame")

    frame.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("filter", "url(#minimapDropShadow)");

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("dragstart.minimap", function() {
        var frameTranslate = d3.demo.util.getXYFromTranslate(frame.attr("transform"));
        frameX = frameTranslate[0];
        frameY = frameTranslate[1];
      })
      .on("drag.minimap", function() {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
        frameX += d3.event.dx;
        frameY += d3.event.dy;
        frame.attr("transform", "translate(" + frameX + "," + frameY + ")");
        var translate =  [(-frameX*scale),(-frameY*scale)];
        target.attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
        zoom.translate(translate);
      });

    frame.call(drag);

    /** RENDER **/
    minimap.render = function() {
      scale = zoom.scale();
      container.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + minimapScale + ")");
      var node = target.node().cloneNode(true);
      node.removeAttribute("id");
      base.selectAll(".minimap .canvas").remove();
      minimap.node.appendChild(node);
      var targetTransform = d3.demo.util.getXYFromTranslate(target.attr("transform"));
      frame.attr("transform", "translate(" + (-targetTransform[0]/scale) + "," + (-targetTransform[1]/scale) + ")")
        .select(".background")
        .attr("width", width/scale)
        .attr("height", height/scale);
      frame.node().parentNode.appendChild(frame.node());
      d3.select(node).attr("transform", "translate(1,1)");
    };
  }


  //============================================================
  // Accessors
  //============================================================


  minimap.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = parseInt(value, 10);
    return this;
  };


  minimap.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = parseInt(value, 10);
    return this;
  };


  minimap.x = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return x;
    x = parseInt(value, 10);
    return this;
  };


  minimap.y = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return y;
    y = parseInt(value, 10);
    return this;
  };


  minimap.scale = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return scale; }
    scale = value;
    return this;
  };


  minimap.minimapScale = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return minimapScale; }
    minimapScale = value;
    return this;
  };


  minimap.zoom = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return zoom;
    zoom = value;
    return this;
  };


  minimap.target = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return target; }
    target = value;
    width  = parseInt(target.attr("width"),  10);
    height = parseInt(target.attr("height"), 10);
    return this;
  };

  return minimap;
};

/** UTILS **/
d3.demo.util = {};
d3.demo.util.getXYFromTranslate = function(translateString) {
  var split = translateString.split(",");
  var x = split[0] ? ~~split[0].split("(")[1] : 0;
  var y = split[1] ? ~~split[1].split(")")[0] : 0;
  return [x, y];
};

/** RUN SCRIPT **/
var canvasWidth = 800;
var shapes = [];
var lastXY = 1;
var zoomEnabled = true;
var dragEnabled = true;

var canvas = d3.demo.canvas().width(435).height(400);
d3.select("#canvas").call(canvas);

d3.select("#resetButton").on("click", function() {
  modeler.reset();
});

d3.xml("http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/wp-content/images/butterfly.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
  addItem(xml.documentElement);
});

function addItem(item) {
  canvas.addItem(d3.select(item));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will only work if you load `minimap.js`  after `<div id="canvas"></div>`  otherwise `d3.select("#canvas").call(canvas);`  would not be able to find the element `#canvas` which would result in the given error.

So the easiest way is to move your `<script src="minimap.js"></script>`  to the end of the `body`. Otherwise you would need to wait until the DOM is ready before you execute the part of the  `minimap`  where `#canvas` is searched and the canvas is initialized.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I always add my scripts or stylesheets under the head tag and at the same time I start my javascript after the document loads :) That was the missing part :) Thanks again.